# Font in math operator

Tags: fonts, math-operators

I'd like to extend the `\min` function by a subscript.
The definition is

```
\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{\operatorname*{min_{{#1}}}}
```

But the fonts of `#1` in `\[ \smoothmin{P,0}_{i=0,\dots,n} \]`
differ from the font in the subscript. I also tried

`\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{\operatorname*{min_{\mathnormal{#1}}}}`,

but this did not help.

What is the correct way of defining the function to have both subscripts in the same font?

Comment: Have you tried `\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{\min_{#1}}` along with `${\smoothmin{P,0}}_{i=0,\dots,n}$`? Or, if you prefer, `\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{\operatorname*{min}_{#1}}` along with `${\smoothmin{P,0}}_{i=0,\dots,n}$`?

Comment: This is not the same in the \\[ … \\] environment. Instead, your solution produces a double subscript.

Comment: Then just use `\operatorname` instead of `\operatorname*`.

Answer (score 5):

`\operatorname` is not the right tool for this job. You might do

```
\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{%
  \operatorname*{min_{\mathgroup=-1 #1}}%
}
```

but an input such as `\smoothmin{P,-1}_{i=0,1,\dots,n}` would produce

[image]

because minus signs become hyphens in the argument to `\operatorname*`.

Fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\smoothmin}[1]{\mathop{\min\nolimits_{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\smoothmin{P,0}_{i=0,\dots,n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A suggestion for being able to use this also in inline formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothmin}{me{_}}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\smoothmin@{{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothmin@}{mm}{\smoothmin@@#1#2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothmin@@}{mmm}{%
  % #1 = math style, #2 = subscript, #3 = optional condition
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \mathop{\min\nolimits_{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
  \else
    \min_{#2\IfValueT{#3}{;\,#3}}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\smoothmin{P,0}_{i=0,\dots,n}a_i
\]
\begin{center}
$\smoothmin{P,0}_{i=0,\dots,n}a_i$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was helpful indeed, thanks!